# How can one extend Activator on iOS to recognize new input gestures?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, activator, cydia-substrate

I'm working on a custom Jailbreak solution on iOS.  I'm trying to be able to add new triggers in Activator.  Specifically I'm trying to define a tap-release-tap-and-hold behavior for the home button although this could theoretically work for any device input.

Now I'm well-versed in MobileSubstrate which lets you do [method swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling) against existing classes at run-time (see here for more info: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) as well as providing other features and benefits.  However, I'm not sure how to get that plugged into Activator since I don't have access to the code, and while I could use ClassDump to export the headers for Activator and sift through them, Activator is an extremely complex application which is why rather than spending a week looking through it all, I'm hoping someone else knows the rough 'injection point' (for lack of a better term) that could get me heading in the right direction.

Note, while I could simply listen for my action at the system level, doing so would short-circuit Activator which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish, which is to add a new action that can be used *with* activator: an Activator extension if you will.

So does anyone have any information on, or a good jumping-off point for achieving this?  I'm hoping for a little direction so I don't have to tear through the entire header class-dump of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'd like to make something like `LAEvent`.
Here are some information may help you start:

1. Implement `LAEventDataSource` protocol

   ```
   @protocol LAEventDataSource <NSObject>

   @required
   - (NSString *)localizedTitleForEventName:(NSString *)eventName;
   - (NSString *)localizedGroupForEventName:(NSString *)eventName;
   - (NSString *)localizedDescriptionForEventName:(NSString *)eventName;

   @optional
   - (BOOL)eventWithNameIsHidden:(NSString *)eventName;
   - (BOOL)eventWithName:(NSString *)eventName isCompatibleWithMode:(NSString *)eventMode;

   @end
   ```
2. Register event data source

   ```
   @interface LAActivator : NSObject
   - (void)registerEventDataSource:(id<LAEventDataSource>)dataSource forEventName:(NSString *)eventName;
   @end
   ```

   Now your event is available in `availableEventNames` property of `LAActivator`

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *availableEventNames;
   ```
3. Send event

   ```
   @interface LAEvent : NSObject<NSCoding>
   + (id)eventWithName:(NSString *)name;
   + (id)eventWithName:(NSString *)name mode:(NSString *)mode;
   - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
   - (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name mode:(NSString *)mode;
   @end

   @interface LAActivator : NSObject
   - (void)sendEventToListener:(LAEvent *)event;
   @end
   ```